# Displaying Game Center GKMatchmakerViewController dismisses other view

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I have a problem when trying to display the GKMatchmakerViewController on my game view.

Normally I create a multiplayer match programmatically by auto-matching 2 opponents, and that works fine.

But when I try to display the standard Game Center Matchmaking view, it dismisses my game view and pushes me back to the menu.

Menu View -> Game View.

I think the problem might be that my menu view acts as my main view and all other views are removed when the Game Center view is displayed (since only one view controller can be shown at the time).

am I setting up my view hierarchy wrong? How should it be done so my Game View wont be dismissed when displaying the Game Center view?

### EDIT - updated with code that calls the GKMatchMakerViewController

GameviewController with method that is called when I want to display the Game Center match making controller

```
  - (void)presentCustomVSBattle {

    ourRandom = arc4random();
    [self setGameState:kGameStateWaitingForMatch];

   AppDelegate * delegate = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;


    [[GCHelper sharedInstance] findCustomMatchWithMinPlayers:2 maxPlayers:2 viewController:delegate.viewController delegate:self];
}
```

// This method is called in GCHelper.m

```
 - (void)findCustomMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController delegate:(id<GCHelperDelegate>)theDelegate {

if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

matchStarted = NO;
self.match = nil;
self.presentingViewController = viewController;
delegate = theDelegate;

if (pendingInvite != nil) {

    [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithInvite:pendingInvite] autorelease];
    mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
      [presentingViewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];

    self.pendingInvite = nil;
    self.pendingPlayersToInvite = nil;
    } 
else {

        [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        request.minPlayers = minPlayers;
        request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
        request.playersToInvite = pendingPlayersToInvite;

        GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
        mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

         [presentingViewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];

        self.pendingInvite = nil;
        self.pendingPlayersToInvite = nil;

    }

}
```

Comment: please post your code showing how you instantiate and display the GKMatchmakerViewController.

Comment: may be you are adding  GKMatchmakerViewController in root AppView Controller

Comment: Thanks, have updated the question, hope that helps.

Comment: If i understand correctly you're calling the method presentCustonVS from GameViewController and want to present the Game Center View in that View Controller. If so, try [[GCHelper sharedInstance] findCustomMatchWithMinPlayers:2 maxPlayers:2 viewController:self delegate:self];

Comment: If I try that @KaanDedeoglu, I get a Warning: "Attempt to present <GKMatchmakerViewController: 0x1c54a3f0> on <GameViewController: 0x1d23a800> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" warning and the Game View is dismissed.

Comment: I display the GameView from my menu view controller like this (if this helps):

 GameViewController *controller = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameViewController" bundle:nil];
        controller.delegate = self;
        controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: okay 2 questions: 1:where is the else{ } part of pendingInvite!=nil in GCHelper code you showed. 2: get rid of the dismissModalViewController lines and try

Comment: Added the else statement - FANTASTIC the dismissModalViewController removal seems to solve the problem! Thank you! Add a answer and I will reward it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the dismissView Controller calls look unnecessary, try getting rid of them :)